# Got a loop in Excel sheet vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a sheet that has a cell to let the user put in a downpayment amount which then displays the percent it is.
I also have another row that has an unlocked cell for the user to enter the percent and it will fill in the downpayment amount. 
I know that this is awkward and actually what I want is to only have 1 cell for downpayment and another for 15% but I was having trouble writing the formula for it.
Because my skill is very bad, I used an event handler on "sheet1 change" that looks for change in those fields and then hides the one that hasn’t been used
The bigger problem is that I have a button on the sheet to CLEAR all of the unlocked cells at once when the calculations are done. The "Clear Cells" button then clears the cells that I have referenced in the "Worksheet Change" code and causes a loop.
If there is a better way to enter a formula on the bar to have only one row that has both the cell for percent and the cell for downpayment amount and have the user enter into one of them and the other autopopulates. ie: downpayment/total amount fills into the % cell. Or if entered into percent then percent * total amount fills the dollar value in downpayment amount.  Sorry if this is confusing I am trying to keep it clear.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$5" Then
        MsgBox "Down Payment Percent Chosen"

        'want to change Range A6 to D6 to hidden or locked
        range("6:6").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$D$6" Then
        MsgBox "Down Payment Amount Chosen"

        'range("B5").Value = 0

        range("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    'If Target.Address = "$D$6" Then
    '    MsgBox "Amount Chosen"
    '    Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    'End If

    'If Target.Address = "$B$5" Then
    '    MsgBox "% Chosen"
    '    Rows("6:6").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    'End If

End Sub

Sub ClearTEst()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rRng As range
    Dim rCell As range
    Dim rRows As range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.range("A1:D28")

    'Need to bring hidden row back
    If Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    If Rows("6:6").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Rows("6:6").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End If


    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

        If rCell.Locked = False Then
            MsgBox "testing"
            Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
            rCell.ClearContents

        End If

    Next rCell

    'got from internet

End Sub
```

Sorry, I have no idea how to make the code formatted in grey for easy viewing here. I see that some of it is in grey but don't exactly know why or how. I selected all of the code and then pressed the code button above but as you can see I could use that help also :)

Thank you 
Carol

Comment: It would be great if you could post a screenshot of your Excel sheet, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disable events temporarily:

```
Sub ClearTEst()
    Dim rRng As Range, rCell As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:D28")

    Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False '<--| no need to check if row is hidden, just set it visible
    Rows("6:6").EntireRow.Hidden = False '<--| no need to check if row is hidden, just set it visible

    Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events handling
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back
    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        If rCell.Locked = False Then
            MsgBox "testing"
            Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
            rCell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next rCell

ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True'<--| enable events handling

End Sub
```

Edit: added change event code with same technique

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events handling
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$B$2" ' Downpayment inout
            Range("B3") =  (Range("B2").Value / Range("B1").Value) * 100
        Case "$B$3" ' Percent entered
            Range("B2").Value =  (Range("B1").Value * Range("B3").Value) / 100
    End Select
ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True'<--| enable events handling
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you user3598756.  I learned from this post.  My bigger issue is what I just answered to Nvj above. Still in a loop with the change event.

Comment: I don't get you: with this solution you won't have any infinite loop with change event. Have you tried it?

Comment: See edited answer where I added the same event enabling/disabling technique to the change dvent handler

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly. I thought that I understood it the first time. Now with your 2nd. edit I put it into practice and now finally understand the .EnableEvents.  I can use it when I clear the page too I believe. Very useful. Thank you so much.!  How do I mark this as answered and give you credit for it? sorry. I am stumbling around and want to follow the ediquette for this site.

Comment: Just click on the check mark besides the answer to toggle it from greyrd out to filled in. Thank you.

Comment: I am loving this solution! I have now added Cases for all of the other cells so that the user can choose either %, Monthly Payment/ Yearly Payment. My whole form can now be finished. I had no idea that there was a way to trigger the change event and then envelope the code to shield it from the event.  thank you. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you want a cell for down payment amount, and one for percent, and you want to auto populate either cell based on the other cell's input.

If that's right, the following is a working example of doing that. The cell B1 contains the total amount, B2 contains the down payment about and B3 contains the percent. If a user edits B2, cell B3 gets populated by the percent and vice-versa.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        ' Downpayment entered
        Percent = (Range("B2").Value / Range("B1").Value) * 100
        Range("B3") = Percent
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        ' Percent entered
        Downpayment = (Range("B1").Value * Range("B3").Value) / 100
        Range("B2").Value = Downpayment
    End If

End Sub
```

If the clear button clears only the user input cells, like the down payment and percent ones, then you can just clear only those cells, without the need to loop through a range to find the unlocked cells. This would increase the performance of your code since it doesn't have to loop through a range.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Nvj.  I originally thought that your answer would work. But it doesn't. It creates a loop that won't end . Every time I enter a number in one of the cells, it of course triggers the change event which in turn runs the code to change the corresponding cell. The debug brings up Downpayment 2E-231 and other such things for a while then I am out of stack?? or was it cache?? either way I would say a stackoverlow :)

Comment: I would like to add that I am not even worrying about the clear cells button at this point as just using the change event is causing the loop. If this gets resolved I believe that it will resolve the clear cells problem also.  How would I now add to my original post with a screen shot?